# How can I enable live error checking in Visual Studio Community for Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I'm using a fresh install of Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac, but can't seem to get errors to display in the errors pad without running my program; on my Windows PC, design-time error checking with VS is automatic. I just updated to Mojave, but was having this issue in my previous Mac operating system.

To be clear, typing incorrect code in a simple console app file (or in a Unity project file, or in a number of other sample solutions that I tried), like `string name = 23.45;`, does not cause an error to be logged in the errors pad unless I run the program.

Is it possible to enable live error checking on VS for Mac, or does this feature only exist on Windows?

Comment: This is not supported. You will see errors highlighted in the text editor as you type but they are not automatically added to the Errors window. Only building would cause errors to be added to the Errors window.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.